# WPF building old version

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, build, compilation

I am building an wpf application. I made some changes like color of buttons and their behavoir like perform something when someone press enter. I am building the solution with clickonce option but visual studio is generating the old files. Like my changes are not compiling and when I run setup file It installs the old version. My latest changes are not showing in the compiled version. Why? Please help.

Comment: Are you running application from the correct directory? Maybe you build Debug, but run app from Release directory?

Comment: I tried deleting the files in debug folder and rebuild it. Still not working

Comment: Describe what do you do exactly, otherwise it will be hard to help. (what do you click, where do you go, what do you run etc.)

Comment: The files in debug do not directly relate to building something with ClickOnce. You need to make sure the path is correct and that the version you are building is newer than an existing version at the deployment path.

Comment: Version is changing automatically and I checked the paths and they are correct.

Comment: In project folder there is a Properties folder. It seems all the files in that folder are old and they are not being updated. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean and Rebuild you project with correct configuration.
2. If you have added any items using "add existing items" try adding it again.
3. If you feel certain files are not updated, try opening it from its correct location, edit it and save. After saving please load it again to the project
4. Try publishing to a different location (other than your OS installed drive)

This is not a solution. But you can try these as a workaround